# Verbatim code environment dash dash

Tags: punctuation, verbatim

I have the following environment for displaying code:

Which works pretty fine but now I have the problem that -- becomes an en dash inside that environment. For example here:

I tried also `{-}{-}` and `-{}-` but inside the Verbatim `{}` are not translated. Any ideas how to escape this the right way?

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn, landscape]{article}     % use "amsart" instead of "article" for AMSLaTeX format
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}                      % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}           % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{frame}
\usepackage{fancybox,calc} 
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{fullpage}
\setlength{\columnsep}{4em}

\newenvironment{code}{\VerbatimEnvironment% 
  \noindent
  %      {\columnwidth-\leftmargin-\rightmargin-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule-4pt} 
  \begin{Sbox} 
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule-4pt}    
  \color{DarkBlue}\begin{Verbatim}
}{% 
  \end{Verbatim}  
  \end{minipage}   
  \end{Sbox} 
  \fcolorbox{DarkBlue}{Orange}{\TheSbox} 
} 

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{code}
git config --global user.name "Max Mustermann"
git config --global user.email "max@mustermann.de"
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It helps tor provide a full MWE, starting with `\documentclass`, so that we know what packages were loaded, as well as other configuration changes or requirements.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: `fancybox` and `fancyvrb` don't work well together. It's `fancybox`'s fault if hyphens are not honored.

Comment: I removed fancyvrb since it is not used anyways. The problem still exists.

Comment: The definition of `Verbatim` made by `fancybox` is faulty. It's better to use `mdframed` and `fancyvrb`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that both `fancyvrb` and `fancybox` define the `Verbatim` environment.

The one defined by `fancybox` has this problem, while the one defined by `fancyvrb` doesn't.

So, loading `fancyvrb` after `fancybox` solves the problem, that is substitute the line

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb,fancybox,calc}
```

with

```
\usepackage{fancybox,fancyvrb,calc}
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn, landscape]{article}     % use "amsart" instead of "article" for AMSLaTeX format
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}                      % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}           % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{frame}
\usepackage{fancybox,fancyvrb,calc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\setlength{\columnsep}{4em}

\newenvironment{code}{\VerbatimEnvironment%
  \noindent
  %      {\columnwidth-\leftmargin-\rightmargin-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule-4pt}
  \begin{Sbox}
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule-4pt}
  \color{DarkBlue}\begin{Verbatim}
}{%
  \end{Verbatim}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{Sbox}%
  \fcolorbox{DarkBlue}{Orange}{\TheSbox}
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{code}
git config --global user.name "Max Mustermann"
git config --global user.email "max@mustermann.de"
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

P.S. I've added a `%` character after `\end{Sbox}` to avoid a spurious space.